# Getting "MsalException: ADFS is not a supported authority" in sample application

Tags: c#, adfs, azure-ad-msal

Using the WPF sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2

And this data:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/start-writing-applications-today-with-the-new-microsoft-authentication-sdks/):

"At the same time, MSAL has a significantly larger scope: whereas ADAL only works with work and school accounts via Azure AD and ADFS), MSAL works with work and school accounts, MSAs, Azure AD B2C and ASP.NET Core Identity, and eventually (**in a future release**) with ADFS"

So currently not supported.